# How to change DrawingVisual Fill and Stroke

Tags: .net, wpf, drawing, fill, stroke

I have a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) object and I want to change its fill and its stroke.

I've tried this for Fill:

```
DrawingVisual MyDrawing = new DrawingVisual();
SetFill(Brushes.Red, MyDrawing.Drawing);
```

Where SetFill is:

```
private void SetFill(Brush fill, DrawingGroup group)
{
    foreach (Drawing drw in group.Children)
    {
        if (drw is DrawingGroup)
            SetFill(fill, drw as DrawingGroup);
        else if (drw is GeometryDrawing)
        {
            GeometryDrawing geo = drw as GeometryDrawing;
            geo.Brush = fill;

            using (DrawingContext context = MyDrawing.RenderOpen())
            {
                context.DrawDrawing(group);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in this way may happen that my DrawingVisual is drawn to a different position, as if the transformations have not been applied more (to MyDrawing).

Also, if I change this instruction: `context.DrawDrawing(group);`
with this other: `context.DrawDrawing(MyDrawing.Drawing);`
I get a strange effect: if I change the Fill the first time nothing happens, while the second the Fill is changed correctly without changing the positions of the figure.

How can I do?

Comment: Did you try to simply set `GeometryDrawing.Brush` recursively, **without** redrawing?

Comment: yes, unfortunately, has no effect.

Comment: I'm afraid your "ugly solution" will end up in more and more drawings, because on every call of `SetFillEx` you put an existing DrawingGroup into the Children collection of a new DrawingGroup.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler approach to your problem (dynamically changing the fill) would be to use an own [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx) for all fills and change its [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.color.aspx) whenever needed.

Comment: Do you mean a SolidColorBrush for each DrawingVisual? How I could change in this way? Could you make a little example? Ps: have you seen my edit?

Comment: In `SetFill` you're trying to set one fill brush for all GeometryDrawings, so they all have the same fill color. You could instead use exactly one SolidColorBrush for all those drawings, when you draw them the first time. Later on, you only need to change that SolidColorBrush, and the fill color of all drawings changes.

Comment: I can't use this solution because i have hundreds of thousands of DrawingVisual and I'd rather not increase the workload; see my last edit.

Comment: What workload? It's just one line of code. Possible misunderstanding: i don't mean one SolidColorBrush **per drawing**, but just one in total, **one for all**. It is so simple!

Comment: Just let me see how i could use this one Brush to change the fill of my DrawingVisual, I think we are misinterpreting.

Comment: Just saw your new question. What about the answer here, have you meanwhile tried it?

Comment: Yes, you were right when you talked about my "ugly solution". I decided to store all brushes because I later found out that to do other things I needed to do that. Do you menn [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715485/blank-screen-using-drawimage-method) question?

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed not required to re-draw the Visuals. 
This should work.

```
private void SetFill(Brush fill, DrawingGroup group)
{
    foreach (Drawing drw in group.Children)
    {
        if (drw is DrawingGroup)
            SetFill(fill, drw as DrawingGroup);
        else if (drw is GeometryDrawing)
        {
            GeometryDrawing geo = drw as GeometryDrawing;
            geo.Brush = fill; // For changing FILL

            // We have to set Pen properties individually.
            // It does not work if we assign the whole "Pen" instance.
            geo.Pen.Brush = fill; 
            geo.Pen.Thickness = 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you've already solved this problem but here is my solution of maybe same thing. I have my own DrawingVisual. It is fresh and not very tested code but for now it works very good:

```
public class MyDrawingVisual : DrawingVisual
{
    private bool myIsSelected = false;

    public VillageInfo VillageInfo { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected 
    {
        get { return myIsSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (myIsSelected != value)
            {
                myIsSelected = value;

                // Retrieve the DrawingContext in order to create new drawing content.
                DrawingContext drawingContext = this.RenderOpen();

                // Create a rectangle and draw it in the DrawingContext.
                Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(VillageInfo.X + 0.1, VillageInfo.Y + 0.1), new System.Windows.Size(0.9, 0.9));
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(myIsSelected ? Colors.White : VillageInfo.Color), (System.Windows.Media.Pen)null, rect);

                // Persist the drawing content.
                drawingContext.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```