# Blank screen using DrawImage method

Tags: .net, wpf, image, drawing, drawimage

I have to draw a bitmap image using [DrawingContext.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606804%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method.

Using the code below everything is working correctly:

```
BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage();
myImage.BeginInit();
myImage.UriSource = new Uri("image.png", UriKind.Relative);
myImage.EndInit();

Rect area = new Rect(new Size(myImage.PixelWidth, myImage.PixelHeight));
DrawingVisual myVisual = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext context = myVisual.RenderOpen())
{ context.DrawImage(myImage, area); }
```

But only if the image does not exceed 2Mb about, i.e. the area (`myImage.PixelWidth x myImage.PixelHeight`) is not larger than 10000x10000. In this case the screen remains blank and no any exception is thrown (so I can not tell if there was an error).

How could I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if the "large" image is properly loaded, i.e. PixelWidth and PixelHeight are as expected?

Comment: Effectively when i draw the "large" image PixelWidth and PixelHeight are 1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like larger images aren't yet loaded when you render them. Try the following to load the bitmap:

```
BitmapSource myImage = BitmapFrame.Create(
    new Uri("image.png"),
    BitmapCreateOptions.None,
    BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

Or this desperate attempt:

```
using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream("image.png", FileMode.Open))
{
    BitmapSource myImage = BitmapFrame.Create(
        fileStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```

Comment: PixelWidth and PixelHeight are always 1

Comment: See edit. I'll immediatly delete it in case it still doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot use CopyTo, i'm working on 3.5 .NET framework, any alternatives?

Comment: Perhaps try without MemoryStream first. See edit. Could you put that image.png somewhere for download?

Comment: I got OutOfMemoryException.The [image](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=C27B6AAFA7EF52E3&id=C27B6AAFA7EF52E3%21243).

Comment: That explains a lot. I tried the image and succeded to load it (which takes a few seconds), but after resizing my windows get OutOfMemoryException, too. Seems that it is simply too large.

Comment: Thanks for your help +1, one last question: if the image is too large why the Windows default photo viewer can display it without problems (also larger images)?

Comment: I just gave it another try and put it in an Image control with `Stretch="None"`, that again in a Grid with `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` and `VerticalAlignment="Center"`. Seems to work quite well. The application consumes about 370 MB memory.